# Unflektiertes Adjektiv?

Tags: grammar-identification, adjective-ending

In der Geschichte 'Der Struwwelpeter' steht:

> Das muß ein trefflich Spielzeug sein.

Meine Frage ist, welcher Regel entsprechend ist es grammatisch "trefflich" da zu nutzen statt von "treffliches". Ist es eher dichterisch so? Kann man mich auf mehr Auskunft hinweisen? Danke

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Das ist ein unflektierter Gebrauch des Adjektivs.

Es gibt viele weitere Beispiele für diese Konstruktion, etwa:

- *Kölnisch Wasser*
- *auf gut Glück*
- *Es ist ein trotzig und verzagt Ding* (Titel einer Kantate von J.S. Bach)
- *Altbundeskanzler*
- *Das hat er alles uns getan, sein groß Lieb zu zeigen an* (7. Strophe des Lieds "Gelobet seist du Jesu Christ" von Martin Luther).

Diese lassen sich in Gruppen einteilen:

- Formelhafte Verbindungen (*Morgenrot, schlecht Wetter droht*; *ruhig Blut*)
- Warenbezeichnungen (*Kölnisch Wasser*)
- Personennamen (*Jung Siegfried*)
- Ortsnamen (*Großschwabhausen*, *Neuruppin*, *Preußisch Oldendorf*)

In allen diesen Gruppen lässt sich argumentieren, dass das Adjektiv und die Nominalphrase als eine Einheit aufgefasst werden, daher wird das Adjektiv nicht flektiert.

Das von dir genannte Beispiel fällt in keine dieser Kategorien.

Ich denke, es handelt sich hier um eine veraltete Form, und die Konstruktion ist hier nur in dem Sinne als "dichterisch" zu verstehen, als dass der Autor eine veraltete (vielleicht zu seiner Zeit: veraltende) Form nutzt. Das Beispiel von *sein groß Lieb* belegt, dass das Phänomen nicht an das neutrale Genus gekoppelt ist. Allerdings treten unflektierte Adjektive wohl vor Allem vor Neutra auf.

Eine ausführlichere Diskussion des Phänomens findest du in *Die unflektierten Adjektive im Deutschen* von Dürscheid und Businger (https://www.ds.uzh.ch/_files/uploads/studarb/index.php?filereq=index.php&filereq=24.pdf). Die Kategorisierung und einige Beispiele, sowie die Bemerkung, dass unflektierte Adjektive häufiger vor Neutra auftauchen, habe ich von dort

Comment: Noch ein Beispiel ist aus Goethes Erlkönig: "Meine Mutter hat manch gülden Gewand".